# Creating mobile responsive site

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment

I recently learned bootstrap css to create web page. But these sites don't appear correctly in mobile devices.

IS there any specific methods or technique so that web pages become both mobile and desktop responsive?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It all just boils down to [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Did you have any alternative to bootstrap?

Comment: Just as I told you above. A lot of trial and error etc. When using percentage instead of pixel widths, will help you a lot.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 3, it will be responsive by default. If you're using Bootstrap 2.x, make sure you're including the responsive CSS. Stick with Bootstrap, its fantastic.